# Password via SSH through command prompt, is it secure

Tags: command-line, ssh, security, batch-file

If I run SSH command via a Windows bat file, is the communication secure. I have the following command in my batch file and it asks for the password once it is executed. I am worried whether the password is transmitted in plain text.

```
ssh -T user1@developer ./remote-tools/ping-208.175.103.123.sh
```

I can't run Wireshark to check as I am on a company laptop in which I do not have the luxury to install software at my wish.

Comment: In 2021 I have abandoned password authentication for SSH connections.  If you have the capability of using a private and public authentication you should.

Comment: You have not provided enough onformation - is the password prompt generated by ssh or the script. (In either case the password is not sent in plain text, but as @Ramhound said - if you are using ssh you are better off using public/private keys - this is usually more secure (unless your private key is stolen) and can be fully automated.

Answer (score -1):

SSH is a comunication protocol meant to be secure.

So why the comunication should be secure while the password transmission shouldn't ?

At most your password could be intercepted by malware on laptop that read pressed keys.

Find a solution to use ssh key as soon as possibile if security concern you and you wanna sleep relaxed.